# Unable to refer an object/variable dynamically during runtime using eval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to import an image in NextJS:

```js
import linkedin from "../public/images/linkedin.webp";
```

While referencing this variable dynamically during runtime:

```js
const socialButtons = [];

for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data.socials).length; i++) {
  socialButtons.push(
    <Image
      src={eval(Object.keys(data.socials)[i])}  //this line gives error
      width={48}
      height={48}
      alt="linkedin"
    />
  );
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

ReferenceError: linkedin is not defined
```

Comment: Your issue could caused by variables obfuscation when NextJS app is compiled, so that defined variable named 'linkedin' will be changed to other name and not existed at runtime. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler

Comment: any way to solve it?

Comment: You could put your imported variable into global window object first, for example `window['linkedin'] = linkedin;`, then later reference it from your eval statement.